# SQL: Calculate the rating based on different columns and use it as an argument

Tags: sql, average, rating

I'm trying to calculate the rating based on a table that has 3 columns with different ratings ranging from 1 to 5.

I wanted to calculate the average of these 3 values and then be able to use this as an argument in queries, for example:

Where Rating >3.5

At this moment I have this that gives me the average for all suppliers

```
SELECT c.Name
    ,(SELECT CAST(AVG(rat) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
        FROM(
            VALUES(b.Qty_Price),
                  (b.Quality),
                  (b.DeliveryTime)) A (rat))  AS Rating
FROM Order a
JOIN Evaluation b ON b.ID_Evaluation  = a.ID_Evaluation 
JOIN Supplier c ON c.NIF_Supplier = a.NIF_Supplier
```

What I would like now is, for example, to filter the providers that have more than 3 ratings, but I don't know how I can do that. If anyone can help i would be grateful

Comment: Can you give sample data and sample results in a table format?

Answer (score 0):

If the query works like you want it, you get the average for all entries, that is.

The `WHERE rating > 3.5`  cannot be added, as `rating` does not exist in the context of the `SELECT`-clause, nor the tables we `JOIN`.

To overcome this issue, we can keep the query that you have made, call it something different using `WITH` and `SELECT` from that sub-query `WHERE rating > 3.5`

It should look something like this:

```
WITH Averages(name, rating) AS
  (SELECT c.name
  ,(SELECT CAST(AVG(rat) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
  FROM(
        VALUES(b.qty_Price),
              (b.quality),
              (b.deliveryTime)) AS (rat))  AS rating
  FROM Order a
  JOIN Evaluation b ON b.ID_Evaluation  = a.ID_Evaluation 
  JOIN Supplier c ON c.NIF_Supplier = a.NIF_Supplier)

SELECT name, rating FROM Averages WHERE rating > 3.5;
```

Now, we simply call the query you provided as `Averages` for example, and we `SELECT` from that table `WHERE rating > 3.5`.

*Also note that you can have multiple `WITH`s to make things easier for you, but remember that a comma (,) is needed to seperate them. In our case, we only have 1 use of `WITH ... AS`, so no need for a comma or semi-colon after `...= a.NIF_Supplier)`*

Looks like you typed only "A" before "(rat)", it should be "AS". Also, remember that attributes should be lowercase, it makes it easier for all of us to distinguish tables from attributes.

*Cheers!*

Comment: Hi my friend, thanks for your answer, but it's not works. When you do "AS rating" we are only create a Alias, we can't use it as argument in WHERE clausure

Comment: Oh no, you're right! What we could do is use a `WITH`-clause for your sub-query- the `SELECT CAST...`. Then, we select from that `WHERE rating > 3.5`. I will modify my answer!